# Leverage Browser Caching not working

Tags: html, css, .htaccess, caching, browser-cache

I have the following code in my .htaccess file to leverage browser caching (and gzip), however when I run tools such as Google Page speed or Gtmetrix I still am getting the error tha my website is not using leverage browser caching. [Link to my website](http://www.ericbartolo.com)

.htaccess code:

```
    <FilesMatch "\.(ico|jpg|jpeg|png|gif|js|css|swf|pdf|flv|mp3)$">
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
 ExpiresActive on
 ExpiresDefault "access plus 14 days"
 Header set Cache-Control "public"

  # My favicon
ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access plus 1 year”

# Images
ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/jpg "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 1 month"

# CSS
ExpiresByType text/css "access 1 month”

# Javascript
ExpiresByType application/javascript "access plus 1 year"

</IfModule>
</FilesMatch>
<FilesMatch "\.(html|htm|xml|txt|xsl)$">
 Header set Cache-Control "max-age=7200, must-revalidate"
</FilesMatch>



<IfModule mod_mime.c>
 AddType application/x-javascript .js
 AddType text/css .css
</IfModule>
<IfModule mod_deflate.c>
 AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/css application/x-javascript text/x-component text/html text/richtext image/svg+xml text/plain text/xsd text/xsl text/xml image/x-icon application/javascript
 <IfModule mod_setenvif.c>
  BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4 gzip-only-text/html
  BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4\.0[678] no-gzip
  BrowserMatch \bMSIE !no-gzip !gzip-only-text/html
 </IfModule>
 <IfModule mod_headers.c>
  Header append Vary User-Agent env=!dont-vary
 </IfModule>
</IfModule>

SetOutputFilter DEFLATE
 <IfModule mod_setenvif.c>
  SetEnvIfNoCase Request_URI \.(?:rar|zip)$ no-gzip dont-vary
  SetEnvIfNoCase Request_URI \.(?:gif|jpg|png)$ no-gzip dont-vary
  SetEnvIfNoCase Request_URI \.(?:avi|mov|mp4)$ no-gzip dont-vary
  SetEnvIfNoCase Request_URI \.mp3$ no-gzip dont-vary
 </IfModule>
```

Comment: I'm confused. When checking your site, it seems that your server is IIS (Server:Microsoft-IIS/8.5) and not Apache. I also noticed that caching information doesn't reflect at all what you posted here. Am I looking to the right place?

Comment: @svpino yes I installed IIS Manager and managed to solve this issue thanks